# Object #<Readable> has no method 'write' while using Gulp + Browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, browserify

When following the [example recipe](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/browserify-transforms.md) from the Gulp.js repository. I get an error:

```
[12:27:31] Using gulpfile C:\GH\riot-tag-build\Gulpfile.js
[12:27:31] Starting 'browserify'...

_stream_readable.js:602
    var written = dest.write(chunk);
                       ^
TypeError: Object #<Readable> has no method 'write'
    at write (_stream_readable.js:602:24)
    at flow (_stream_readable.js:611:7)
    at _stream_readable.js:579:7
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)
```

I have tried to modify the source code to match my requirements and this is the Gulpfile I am trying to run with no luck.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var riotify = require('riotify');
var transform = require('vinyl-transform');
var buffer = require('gulp-buffer');

gulp.task('browserify', function () {
  // set up the browserify instance on a task basis
  var b = browserify({debug: true});
  // transform regular node stream to gulp (buffered vinyl) stream
  var browserified = transform(function(filename) {
    b.add(filename);
    return b.bundle();
  });

  return gulp.src('./main.js')
    .pipe(browserified)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['browserify']);
```

And the whole example can be found from [here](https://github.com/ttamminen/riot-tag-build/)

Any ideas why the stream might be read-only? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Check the recipe again -- it was [updated](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/commit/75b5b74be0b0d37c10425363ac72e498c1bf012b) shortly after you posted this question.  @ddprrt's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29430741/765987) looks correct based on the updated recipe

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the entries: './entry.js', .pipe(source('app.js')) part.  In the old version, a source file was specified once: './app.js'  But in the new version there's this entry.js introduced. What is that file and why is it involved?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I get the same problem. And I find the solution. You just downgrade "browserify" version to the latest 9.0.4. And anything will be ok. You can reference the commit history.

https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/commits/master

====Update====

I solve this error. I use 'through2', the code is as follows.

```
gulp.src('./src/index.js')
    .pipe(through2.obj(function (file, enc, next){
            browserify(file.path)
                .bundle(function(err, res){
                    // assumes file.contents is a Buffer
                    file.contents = res;
                    next(null, file);
                });
        }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'))
```

The solution is from this issue.

https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/1044

Comment: Thanks for this post. The hint to use browserify 9.0.4 ist good. But it must be 9.0.4, 9.0.8 for example is also not working.. you can achieve this in your package.json with this: "browserify": "9.0.4" or when you install it via your terminal: npm install browserify@9.0.4

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure about vinyl-transform, but I guess the correct way of using browserify is to use it as the start point, and transform the stream afterwards to a vinyl object. At least that's what's in the recipes.

```
var gulp       = require('gulp'),
    source     = require('vinyl-source-stream'),
    browserify = require('browserify');

gulp.task('browserify', function () {
  return browserify({
    debug: true,
    entries: ['./main.js']
  }).bundle()
    .pipe(source('main.bundle.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});
```

Comment: Your example works smoothly, thanks! I'll wait for other answers that might explain the original problem, but if nothing shows up then I'll accept this as an answer. I would like to learn what they did in the linked recipe.

Comment: How about defining the transform in the browserify object i.e : browserify({transform:[riotify]}).https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/browserify-transforms.md  ... Besides facing the same problem myself..

Comment: @user3340677 I have tried it in the example I pasted: var b = browserify({debug: true, transform: ['riotify'] }); but it didn't help. The transform below it is vinyl-transform which is completely different beast.